# Copying a boxed value

Tags: c#, boxing

Question about boxing...

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
int k = 4;
object oi = i;
object oj = j;
object ok = k;

oi = oj;
object o = ok;
```

Do the last 2 lines cause 2 new re-boxings?

What does it mean to assign one boxed value to another boxed value, like in next to last line?

What does it mean to assign a boxed value to a new object variable, like in last line?

Answer (score 2):

```
oi = oj;
object o = ok;
```

Boxed values are objects. There're just normal reference copy. No boxing involved. Also,

> What does it mean to assign one boxed value to another boxed value, like in next to last line?

You're not assign a value to `another value`. You just assigned the value to "variable" `oi`.

Comment: So when you box a value like object oi=i, then an object is allocated to house the value of i. When you do oi=oj, you are overriding the oi reference with the oj reference, so now oi is pointing at j wrapper, what happens to the object allocated to wrap i?

Comment: Nothing happened. You just removed a reference to this object. If nothing else is referencing to it, it would be GCed later.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always check the IL:

```
// int i = 2;
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // i
// int j = 3;
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0003:  stloc.1     // j
// int k = 4;
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_0005:  stloc.2     // k
// object oi = i;
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0007:  box         System.Int32
IL_000C:  stloc.3     // oi
// object oj = j;
IL_000D:  ldloc.1     // j
IL_000E:  box         System.Int32
IL_0013:  stloc.s     04 // oj
// object ok = k;
IL_0015:  ldloc.2     // k
IL_0016:  box         System.Int32
IL_001B:  stloc.s     05 // ok
// oi = oj;
IL_001D:  ldloc.s     04 // oj
IL_001F:  stloc.3     // oi
// object o = ok;
IL_0020:  ldloc.s     05 // ok
IL_0022:  stloc.s     06 // o
```